# Bitcoin disappeared from Trezor wallet

Tags: security, trezor

Originally I installed my Trezor wallet onto my wife's computer (since my computer doesn't have a USB 2.0 port). Later, I bought an adapter and decided to transition the Trezor wallet to my computer. I went through the process and added a passphrase (which I had not previously done on my wife's computer). I am aware that the passphrase has to be exact, because entering a different passphrase will just bring me to a new wallet. I am sure that the passphrase is correct.

Confusingly, it looks like all of my Bitcoin was transferred out of my wallet when I [view it on Bitcoin Explorer](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/18FwPtWmMC4KfXszVvar5g4145wn8TmpqR). I did not make this transaction and frankly I can't really tell what this transaction means. I am at a loss for where it went and how to get it back.

Any thoughts on what could have happened? Is this a bug?

Comment: To which wallet in your computer did you type your seed phrase?
Chances are that the wallet application in your computer could have been compromised

Comment: I did it in the Trezor Suite. I entered the seed phrase and then immediately after chose the passphrase. Is it possible that the Trezor Suite was hacked?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you must have entered it in a phishing site that looks like trezor suite.
AFAIK you don't need to enter a seed phrase to transact from Trezor, because the hardware wallet does all the transaction signing for you.

**SEED phrases should never be disclosed**

Always use the official website https://wallet.trezor.io/

Answer (score 2):

You should never have entered the seed phrase into a computer. The seed phrase is for emergency use only if the Trezor wallet is lost or compromised.

There is no such thing as transitioning a wallet to a different computer or installing the wallet on a computer. The wallet is in the Trezor, period. You should install the Trezor *software* on another computer so that computer can also access the Trezor, but the wallet remains in the Trezor at that time and the passphrase is not involved in any way.

By entering the passphrase, you compromised the wallet. The passphrase is only supposed to be in the Trezor itself, it isn't supposed to be on any computer and certainly not ever on one connected to the Internet.

The reason you keep the passphrase is in case the Trezor is ever lost, compromised, or damaged. In that case, you can program a new Trezor on a computer that is not connected to the Internet or otherwise securely recover the wallet.